# Adobe Fireworks CS6 - JPEG always saves at 100% ? Is this a bug?

Tags: adobe, photoshop, fireworks

Working on OS X Mountain Lion with Adobe Fireworks 6.

Every single time I go to Save As.. and choose JPEG I go to options and modify then go to Options to adjust the Quality to ~80% from the default 99% it never retains this value.

I will adjust the quality to 80%, click Okay and if I return to options it's back at 99% quality.

If I set quality to 80%, hit okay, and then save the file I see that after inspection it saved it again at 99% quality (can tell by the file size.)

Why is Fireworks CS6 not retaining my options setting for JPEG quality? Anyone else experiencing this?

This is frustrating because I recall a couple months ago where I was unable to save as a PNG32 because the options always reverted back to PNG24. That problem seemed to go away on it's own.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the "Save As" JPG options inherit their values from whatever is set in the Optimize panel (which by default in a new file is 80% for JPG). If you change the value in the Optimize panel, the "Save As" JPG options will use the new value, even if you change the Optimize panel to a different format.

This is probably the same root cause of your PNG24/PNG32 issue -- I have experienced the same problem with the Export command, which also keys off the Optimize panel settings.